# Не загружаются фотографии (VK API)

Tags: php, vkontakte-api, curl

Здравствуйте. Нужно загрузить фотографии в VK по ссылке, полученной методом `photos.getWallUploadServer`.

Как загружаю:

```
 $photos = array();
 $photos['file1'] = '@17.png';

 $ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $upl_url); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,  $photos);
$otvet = curl_exec($ch); 
curl_close($ch);

print_r($otvet);
```

Данным способом не получается.
URL получаю правильный (проверял пробуя загрузить через обычную HTML форму). Также фотографии загружаются кодом, который нашёл где-то:

```
 exec("curl -X POST -F 'file1=@17.png' '$upl_url'", $output);
```

Уже много чего перепробовал,но через curl не хочет. Надеюсь на вашу помощь.

Comment: Говоря "Не работает", приводите пример ошибки, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так

```
$curl = curl_init($upl_url);
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_POST => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array(
        'file1' => curl_file_create('17.png'),
    ),
));
$otvet = curl_exec($curl); 
if (curl_errno($curl)) {
    echo "cURL error: ", curl_error($curl);
}

curl_close($curl);

print_r($otvet);
```

Comment: Там еще есть тонкость с `CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD => FALSE` так как эта опция отвечает за возможность загрузки файлов и про нее не всегда понятно как настроено